# Reading a File using JS and displaying its contents in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, file

So, I'm trying to make an .html file, where I can select any type of file, say .txt, or .html or .py, and have the contents of said file into a textarea on my html page. How do I go about doing this? I have no clue where to start.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       console.log(xhttp.responseText);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "you_file_path", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Replace **you_file_path** with you link

Comment: Is there a way I can use a dropdown instead of having to provide the path?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new to javascript....how would I assign a variable to the contents of the file I called?

Comment: yes, you can call the API when select input changed